# Generic method, is it possible to return a StreamReader instance?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, c#-4.0, generics

I've come across a post where Jon Skeet posted the following:

> You can't use any parameterised constructor. You can use a
>   parameterless constructor if you have a "where T : new()" constraint.

I have the following method:

```
public T ReturnReader<T>(String filePath) where T : TextReader, new()
{
    return new T(filePath);
}
```

which violates what he mentions above. I need the above method to be able to return both a StreamReader (production code) and a StringReader (unit testing purposes). As far as i can see, streamReader doesnt contain a parameterless constructor so i cant create a parameterless instance and then assign the filePath to it in the calling method.

Anyone see a solution to this?

Thanks for your time!

**EDIT:** original Methods, A and B

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Ensures number of columns stated == number of columns in file.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="errorMessageList">A running list of all errors encountered.</param>
    public static void ValidateNumberOfColumns(string filePath, int userSpecifiedColumnCount, List<String> errorMessageList)
    {
        int numberOfColumnsInFile = GetNumberOfColumnsInFile(filePath, errorMessageList);

        if (userSpecifiedColumnCount != numberOfColumnsInFile) errorMessageList.Add("Number of columns specified does not match number present in file.");
    }

    public static int GetNumberOfColumnsInFile(string filePath, List<String> errorMessageList)
    {
        int numberOfColumns = 0;
        string lineElements = null;

        try
        {
            using (StreamReader columnReader = new StreamReader(filePath))
            {
                lineElements = columnReader.ReadLine();
                string[] columns = lineElements.Split(',');
                numberOfColumns = columns.Length;
            }
            return numberOfColumns;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            errorMessageList.Add(ex.Message);
            return -1;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have to resort to reflection to make code feasible for unit testing, that's a bit of a smell - only an *indication* that you may want to reconsider the design, but certainly something to think about.

I would be tempted to abstract this into a separate interface - `IPathReader` or something similar:

```
public interface IPathReader
{
    TextReader CreateReader(string path);
}
```

Then inject that into the class that you're testing - with an implementation using `StringReader` in testing, and an implementation using `StreamReader` in production. (I *suspect* you don't really need it to return different types.)

Note that this is effectively just a `Func<string, TextReader>` - so you could use that instead of an interface if you wanted.

Comment: You may be right regarding reconsidering the design since this is my first attempt at unit testing. The issue i had was that i had method A, calling Method B. Method B returns an int and uses StreamReader. So in order to test Method B i needed to Mock the StreamReader. The problem arised when i went to test MethodA. If you would like, i can post the original 2 methods as an edit in my question.

Comment: I guess im missing something as I still dont follow how separating this into a second interface would solve my problem.

Comment: @HansRudel: A second interface? What's the first interface? It looks to me like part of the problem is that you're using *static* methods, which makes dependency injection at an object level tricky. You could pass a collaborator into the actual method, but otherwise you might want to try making them *instance* methods, and pass the "path to reader" factory into the constructor.

Comment: this is how the classes/interface look atm.  http://pastebin.com/RcyZWmfL 
Im already using DI to solve the issue of the StreamReader/other IO dependencies. Any pointers your willing to give with regards to how this should be structured would be very welcome. Thanks for your time!

Comment: @HansRudel: Okay, that looks about right, yes. (I'd question some of your names, but that's a different matter.) So to test `EntityVerification` you just pass in a stub implementation of `IIOManager`.

Comment: so from a design perspective, i havent done something less than ideal/stupid? Yeah im still trying to work on my naming skills. Regarding testing, the following is what i have. http://pastebin.com/LZ5RYusj  Thanks for your comments.

Comment: @HansRudel: Looks reasonable, other than `IIOManager.GetNumberOfColumnsInFile` - which is more about interpreting data than just retrieving it. I'd try to make `IIOManager` as dumb as possible, putting more logic on things that depend on it. It'll make it easier to test that logic..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14594/discussion-between-hans-rudel-and-jon-skeet)

Answer (score 5):

`Activator.CreateInstance` it's not good idea because it's too expensive, so you could try this

```
    StringReader reader = ReturnReader(() => new StringReader(filePath));
    StreamReader streamReader = ReturnReader(() => new StreamReader(filePath));

    private T ReturnReader<T>(Func<T> reader)
        where T : TextReader
    {
        return reader();
    }
```

**EDIT**

as per code, I think the best way is to separate NumberOfColumns and getting first row. So the new  method NumberOfColumns will not depend from stream readers

Answer (score 4):

You can easily accomplish this by using reflection:

```
    public T ReturnReader<T>(String filePath) where T : TextReader
    {
        return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T),filePath);
    }
```

Usage:

```
        var rdr = ReturnReader<StringReader>("c:\\test.txt");
        var rdr2 = ReturnReader<StreamReader>("c:\\test.txt");
```

Comment: any ideas how to solve the following the?

using (StreamReader columnReader = (StreamReader)ReturnReader<T>(filePath))

It says i cant convert T to StreamReader

Comment: ?? "StreamReader class doesn't have a constructor takes string" it does have a constructor that accepts a string, unless ive misunderstood? 

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/f2ke0fzy(v=vs.80)

Comment: You are right, it has the constructor that takes path, I was using Framework 4 Client Profile on my test project.

Comment: (StreamReader columnReader = ReturnReader<StreamReader>(filePath)) should work.